# passing props/attribute to nested component inside custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to know what is the best way to pass many props to a component that is wrapped inside an external component, for example

**code**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-text-field
                :error="summonerNameError"
                :loading="summonerNameLoading"
                @input="onSummonerNameChange($event)"
                label="Nom Invocateur"
                v-model="summonerName"
                :solo="inputSolo"
                :flat="inputFlat"
        ></v-text-field>
    </div>
</template>
```

here if i want to pass multiple properties to v-text-field from outside, should i just created a prop on the `component` and pass it to the nested `v-text-field`, or there is a better way?

Comment: You can also use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to better manage multiple prop states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a question I had also and I found the solution into [this very interesting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YZ5DwlLSt8&list=LLlP1FDszsLUkjodtv-uYMGg&index=2&t=2367s) from Chris Fritz:

He calls that a *transparent wrapper*:

So there are two things to deal with, listeners and attributes:

For listeners:

```
<v-text-field v-on="$listeners"></v-text-field>
```

For attributes, it's just a little bit more tricky. By default, Vue passes all the attributes to the root tag of your component. Here, you root tag is a div but you want to pass the attributes to your `v-text-field` component. You need to use the `inheritsAttrs: false` into your Vue Component:

```
export default {
    inheritsAttrs: false
    ...
}
```

And then use the same technique on your `v-text-field` component by using:

```
<v-text-field v-bind="$attrs"></v-text-field>
```

You should then have something like

```
<v-text-field v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs"></v-text-field>
```

And then you should be able to add whatever you like. Hope this helps!

PS: The video talks about this trick from [21:48](https://youtu.be/7YZ5DwlLSt8?t=1308)

Hope this helps!